# What is the floating point precision on Nexus 6, Nexus 5 and LG-D690 Smartphones?

Tags: hardware, tech-specs

After researching on the internet, I could not find specs for this. This is the best I got, but didnt solve my query -> http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/google-nexus-6,4093-7.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about hardware Floating Point Unit - it is the IEEE 754 spec, see: http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/vector-floating-point.php

If you are talking about the Java language which is used to write apps on Android: its still the IEEE 754 spec, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java

Because binary cannot accurately represent all of the numbers in decimal format, the IEEE 754 spec puts boundaries on acceptable error. If you are wondering about why your calculator app seems to handle all floating numbers correctly - it is probably using a different numeric representation system like BigDecimal.